# display only the values that are NOT in some table. MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `matches`, in which users get to decide who they like. For example:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | users_id | match_id |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | 1        | 2        |
| 2  | 1        | 3        |
| 3  | 2        | 1        |
| 4  | 3        | 2        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

As seen above, the first user chose users `2` and `3`, the second chose `1` and the third chose `2`. First and second users are now mutual ([demo in fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sem1VuyPThKc7f9mQJyVHw/9), works in v5.5).

...and in case the rest of the internet breaks...

```
CREATE TABLE watched (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `users_id` INTEGER,
  `watched` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO watched
  (`id`, `users_id`, `watched`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'movie1'),
  ('2', '1', 'movie2'),
  ('3', '1', 'movie3'),
  ('4', '2', 'movie2'),
  ('5', '2', 'movie1'),
  ('6', '3', 'movie1'),
  ('7', '3', 'movie5'),
  ('8', '3', 'movie4');

  CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(355),
  `email` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO users
  (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'name1', 'email1@mail.com'),
  ('2', 'name2', 'email2@mail.com'),
  ('3', 'name3', 'email3@mail.com');

  CREATE TABLE profile (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `users_id` INTEGER,
  `about` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO profile
  (`id`, `users_id`, `about`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'something about me'),
  ('2', '2', 'something about me'),
  ('3', '3', 'something about me');

  CREATE TABLE matches (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `users_id` INTEGER,
  `match_id` VARCHAR(355)
);

INSERT INTO matches
  (`id`, `users_id`, `match_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2'),
  ('2', '1', '3'),
  ('3', '2', '1'),
  ('4', '3', '2');

  SELECT u1.users_id as me,
       u2.users_id as matched,
       p.*, u.*
from matches u1
join matches u2 on u2.match_id = u1.users_id 
and u2.users_id = u1.match_id    
JOIN users u ON u.id=u1.match_id 
JOIN profile p ON p.users_id=u1.match_id 
where u1.users_id = 1
group by me, matched
```

Now, there's another query, which displays users' matched movie titles with other users. For example, if `user1` watched a movie called `movie1` and another `user2` watched `movie1` too, then it will display the number of matched movies(`num_movies`), their titles, and other information, such as users' emails etc (from tables `users` and `profile`) with that user:

```
    $movies = mysqli_query($connect, 
    "
    SELECT w1.users_id user1
         , u.name 
         , p.*
         , u.*
         , w2.users_id user2
         , COUNT(w2.watched) num_movies
         , GROUP_CONCAT(w2.watched ORDER BY w2.watched) movies 
      FROM watched w1 
      JOIN watched w2 
        ON w2.watched = w1.watched 
       AND w2.users_id != w1.users_id 
      JOIN users u 
        ON u.id = w1.users_id 
      JOIN profile p 
        ON p.users_id = w1.users_id 
     WHERE w1.users_id = $id 
     GROUP 
        BY user1
         , user2
");

while ($row = $movies->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "matched with id {$row['user2']} {$row['num_movies']} times on titles {$row['movies']}\n";
}
```

Or see the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rk4mLSzj7abpeonv4LQYex/0).

And I want to make it so that the query above will display only the users that are NOT mutual, that is, the users that aren't in the table `matches`. In our case, with the main user being `user2`, it should display only the `user3` and their matched movie titles etc.

How can I make it so?

I tried adding something like 
`join matches m on m.users_id!=w2.users_id`
 or `m.match_id in(select match_id from matches)!=w2.users_id` but these don't seem to work.

Comment: What you have to select : [ 1,2] and [2,1] not exist right?

Comment: yes, I guess so. It should also work with other ids too..

Comment: i have a suggestion here, make your id's `auto increment` and `not null` so that you have nothing to do with them, it will make your job a bit easier( sorry for not having a relevant answer for your problem:( )

Comment: yes, thank you! they are in my actual table)

Comment: SELECT mutual users and display movie watched by them, right is that your problem.

Comment: yes.. but SELECT those that aren't mutual, rather

Comment: @InterviewSortout ohh I get it now!! `What you have to select : [ 1,2] and [2,1] not exist right` can you show me how to do it? I couldn't figure out..

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is

- start from the `user` table
- inner join the `watched` on the user_id
- inner join again the `watched` on the user_id is different from the current user and the same movie name

This way you get all the movies liked by each user with any other user.

What is remaining is to filter out mutual users for each user. To do this, you can:

- left join `matches` on user_id and match_id
- group by user1, user2
- count distinct matches ids
- filter out when count = 2(mutual friends)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT u.*, u.id as user1, w2.users_id as user2, count(DISTINCT m.id) AS matched, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w1.watched ORDER BY w1.watched) AS movies, COUNT(DISTINCT w1.id) AS num_movies
FROM users u
INNER JOIN watched w1 ON w1.users_id = u.id
INNER JOIN watched w2 ON (w1.users_id != w2.users_id) AND w2.watched = w1.watched
LEFT JOIN matches m ON (m.users_id = w1.users_id AND m.match_id = w2.users_id) OR (m.users_id = w2.users_id AND m.match_id = w1.users_id)
WHERE w1.users_id < w2.users_id
GROUP BY user1, user2
HAVING matched < 2
```

[Example query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8tsVtDY2PB1ARDkrnMVYX6/1)